# DotVVM extension install errors on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, dotvvm

I'm attempting to install DotVVM in Visual Studio 2019. Right now I can find it when I 'manage extensions' and it downloads and installs without error. However when I restart Visual Studio post installation I get an error stating 'The DotVVM package did not load correctly' and points me to an xml output file. The contents of said file shows:

> SetSite failed for package [DotvvmPackage]
> Source: System.ComponentModel.Composition
> Description: The composition produced multiple composition errors, with 3 root causes. The root causes are provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information

> 1. No exports were found that match the constraint: ContractName DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogFactory RequiredTypeIdentity DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogFactory Resulting in: Cannot set import DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.VsPackages.DotvvmPackageDependencies.DialogFactory (ContractName='DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.DialogFactory') on part DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.VsPackages.DotvvmPackageDependencies.Element: DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.VsPackages.DotvvmDependencies.DialogFactory (ContractName='DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogFactory') DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.VsPackages.DotvvmPackageDependencies

> 2. No exports were found that match the constraint:
>    Pretty much the same error except it's talking about 'DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.Common.Licensing.ILoginProvider'

> 3. No exports were found that match the constraint:*
>    Same error except it's talking about 'DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.Services.CommandService'

Now I have been trying to find other topics and came across many that said to delete (or rename) the '%appData%'/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/16.0/ComponentModelCache' folder which I've tried with no luck. Removed it out of every VisualStudio version folders as well. Restarted Visual Studio of course after. That folder did rebuild itself but I got the same error again.

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling it as well. Tired with running Visual Studio as an admin for kicks. Even downloaded the DotVVM.Integration.VisualStudio.2019.RTM.vsix file directly (both 4.0.534 and 4.0.539) and installing it that way with no luck.

I also tried fully uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio 2019 all together with no luck. I made sure the entire VisualStudio/16.0 folder was also gone between installs.

I have been able to install other extensions alright just to see.

It seems like I'm missing something or some files when it's trying to install, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your exact version of Visual Studio 2019? Make sure you have installed all updates  - we support only the most recent update because Microsoft changes some internal APIs the extension is using, and it is impossible to keep everything in sync with older updates.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply - When I run the 'Check for updates' it claims it is to to date. I mistakenly took that to mean it was really up to date. Turns out my cooperate environment has me locked down to 16.10.2 as the latest version I'm allowed to have. Once I realized that I was able to find an older DotVVM (2.5.254) which supports the version of visual studio I have. That installed fine. I think that's the best I'm able to get with the version I'm restricted to. 

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my version of Visual Studio was the issue. My cooperate environment locks me to 16.10.2 which is not the latest version. Visual Studio updates claims I'm up to date but I am not.

The version of DotVVM (4.0.539) doesn't support version 16.10.2 of visual studio, hence the error. I did find an older version of DotVVM (2.5.254) that does support that version of visual studio and that worked fine.